# Why is my xpath not working with selenium?

Tags: python, django, selenium, xpath

I need to write a script that given the user's input in my website it connects to this page to submit the number and download a file. The thing is, the xpath is not working at all. What am I doing wrong?

This is the view (I deleted the parts not relevant to the question):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import requests
from django.views.generic import FormView


from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

class ConstanciaInscripcion(FormView):

    def get(self, request):
       return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
    
    def post(self,request):

        form = MonotributoForm(request.POST)
        email = request.POST['Email']
        cuit_r = int(request.POST["CUIT"])
           
        #Selenium script
        DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/Users/python/chromedriver.exe'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
        driver.get('https://seti.afip.gob.ar/padron-puc-constancia-internet/ConsultaConstanciaAction.do')

        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        cuit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cuit']").send_keys(cuit_r)
        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='btnConsultar']").click()
            
        return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
```

The website also has a captcha and I was given a method to deal with it, should I also add the captcha field to a driver.find_element and pass the method there?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your implicit wait method is not enough. You should try explicit wait. Basically, An explicit wait is a code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code: [Source](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Another reason could be dynamic id's. Maybe your website create different Id's every time. You should find other attribute which is not changing every time then change your Xpath according to this attribute or you could use full(absolute) Xpath which doesn't need any particular attribute name.